# Django view ignoring second argument

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I have a menu-content system in Django, where menu items are accessed by their keys and their contents through IDs. My URL mapping is:

```
url(r'^menu/(?P<item_key>[a-z/\-]*[a-z])/', views.menu, name='menu'),
url(r'^menu/(?P<item_key>[a-z/\-]*[a-z])/(?P<content_id>\d+)/', views.menu,\
                                               name='menu_showById'),
```

The first one is the base view, where the user would land after clicking on an item through the navbar. The second one is for viewing a particular content in a menu item. `views.menu` has an optional parameter called content_id with `None` as default (in which case it views the newest content).

The navbar links work fine, pointing to the menu items as `http://localhost:8000/menu/some-item/sub-item`. In this URL generated in the template using `{% url 'data:menu' node.key %}`[1], `/menu/` is the view and `some-item/sub-item` is the item_key (example matches real use case; there are dashes and forward slashes in *almost* all of the item keys).

Through the base view, I click on a link generated with `{% url 'data:menu_showById' menuItem.key cItem.id %}` as `http://localhost:8000/menu/some-item/sub-item/2/`, to view the content with the ID 2. There's nothing wrong with the generated URLs, they look exactly as I want them to and the URL mapping regexes match them properly.

The problem is, while `menu_showById` gets the `item_key` parameter properly as `some-item/sub-item`, the second parameter `content_id` is never captured.

...Why?

^[1]: `node` is a node in the django-mptt tree structure I use to keep my menu items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first regex is always matching, so content_id is never picked up. Try switching the order in urls.py.

Answer (score 1):

Lesson learned: Keep your URL regexes as strict as possible. The answer by scoopseven was the most obvious solution and an important rule in defining URLs, but using it to fix something like this kinda felt like a hack to me, and more importantly made the order of my URLs into one I didn't like. So I changed the base URL from

`url(r'^menu/(?P<item_key>[a-z/\-]*[a-z])/', views.menu, name='menu')`

to

`url(r'^menu/(?P<item_key>[a-z/\-]*[a-z])/$', views.menu, name='menu')`

and now it works like a charm.

Comment: I was going to suggest that, too. We don't do that for a particular reason. Say you get /menu/someitemkeythatdoesntmatchregex/somethingelse/, it will never get caught by the lowest level regex because of the $. That's the desired behavior in our application, yours may differ.

Comment: True, that is very application dependent. In that case, I would simply view a 404 anyway. But yes, I see how a match-all regex after the specifics might be useful as well. Thanks again for the insight.